# What Surface to use for eglMakeCurrent for context that only renders into FBOs

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I'm having the following situation:

In a cross platform rendering library for iOS and Android (written in c(++)), i have two threads that each need their own EGLContext:
Thread A is the main thread; it renders to the Window.
Thread B is a generator thread, that does various calculations and renders the results into textures that are later used by thread A.

Since i can't use EGL on iOS, the library uses function pointers to static Obj.-C functions to create a new context and set it current.
This already works, i create the context for thread A using

```
EAGLContext *contextA = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
```

The context for thread B is created using

```
EAGLContext *contextB = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 sharegroup:[contextA sharegroup]];
```

I can then set either of the two current:

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
```

To use the same logic (function pointers passed to the library) on Android, i want to do this in the C side of the JNI bindings, this time using real EGL instead of Apple's EAGL.
I can easily create contextA using a WindowSurface and the native Window, i can create contextB and pass contextA to the shareContext parameter of the eglCreateContext call.

But when i want to make contextB current, i have to pass a surface to the eglMakeCurrent call, and i'm trying to figure out what kind of surface to pass there.

- I cannot use the WindowSurface i use for contextA as the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.4.20130211.pdf) says in section 3.7 that "At most one context for each supported client API may be current to a particular thread at a given time, and at most one context may be bound to a particular surface at a given time."
- I cannot specify EGL_NO_SURFACE, because that would result in an EGL_BAD_MATCH error in the eglMakeCurrent call.
- It seems I could use a PBuffer surface, but I hesitate because I'd have to specify the width and height when I create such a surface, and thread B might want to create textures of different sizes. In addition to that, the ["OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide"](http://opengles-book.com/) by Munshi, Ginsburg, and Shreiner states in section 3.8 that "Pbuffers are most often used for generating texture maps. If all you want to do is render to a texture, we recommend using framebuffer objects [...] instead of pbuffers because they are more efficient", which is exactly what i want to do in thread B.

I don't understand what Munshi, Ginsurg and Shreiner mean by that sentence, how would a framebuffer object be a replacement for a pbuffer surface? What if I create a very small (say 1x1px) pbuffer surface to make the context current - can i then still render into arbitrarily large FBOs? Are there any other possibilities I'm not yet aware of?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a PBuffer surface (sized 1x1) - i then create an FBO and render into textures just fine. For displaying them (in a different thread and a different (shared) opengl context), i use a windowsurface with an ANativeWindow (there's a sample of that somewhere in the sdk).

Answer (score 3):

The surface you pass to eglMakeCurrent() must be an EGL surface from eglCreateWindowSurface().  For example:

```
    EGLSurface EglSurface = mEgl.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEglDisplay, maEGLconfigs[0], surfaceTexture, null);
    mEgl.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, EglSurface, EglSurface, mEglContext);
```

But, eglCreateWindowSurface() requires a SurfaceTexture which is provided to the onSurfaceTextureAvailable() callback when a TextureView is created, but you can also create off-screen SurfaceTextures without any View.

There is an example app that uses TextureView in the Android SDK here, although it uses the SurfaceTexture for camera video rather than OpenGL ES rendering:

```
sources\android-17\com\android\test\hwui\GLTextureViewActivity.java
```

By default, the EGL surface for FBOs will have the same size as the SurfaceTexture they were created from.  You can change the size of a SurfaceTexture with:

```
    surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(width, height);
```

Don't use pbuffers on Android because some platforms (Nvidia Tegra) do not support them.
This article explains the advantages of FBOs over pbuffers in detail:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES

Comment: Could you please explain how you can create an off-screen SurfaceTexture without any view? I know it's a broad question, but just a few hints will suffice.

Comment: Essentially, you use the new operator, like this:mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(1);
mSurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(miMaxWidth, miMaxHeight);

Comment: Can this be done from native code? I tried to use SurfaceTexture (including the header from frameworks/native/include/gui/SurfaceTexture.h) but I still get a compile error: declaration of SurfaceTexture cannot be found in this scope.

Comment: Probably not.  You should construct the SurfaceTexture in Java and pass it to eglCreateWindowSurface() in Java also.  The EGL surface (and context) from this can be passed to your native code and used there.

Comment: @ClayMontgomery creating a SurfaceTexture requires a valid GL texture name on a pre-existing context (made with glGenTextures()). This basically means that to create an offscreen context with SurfaceTexture the way you suggest, you first need to have an *onscreen* context available. Is that correct?

Comment: The texture name is not required to be assigned by glGenTextures().  You can simply assign them yourself beginning at 1.  You must have a valid EGL context to call eglGetDisplay (EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY), but there is no requirement to ever make a window with that context that is on screen.

Comment: @ClayMontgomery you say the surface passed to `eglMakeCurrent` "must" be from `eglCreateWindowSurface`, but both myself and Pontomedon are using pbuffer surfaces. Is "must" not strictly true here? Or maybe you are assuming different constraints (e.g. maybe not every EGL implementation offers pbuffer surfaces?) I have no idea.

Comment: @myself Appears to be a compatibility issue. (Note that SurfaceTexture is not available until API 11, so there is clearly a tradeoff here.)

Answer (score 0):

If drawing to FBO is the only things you want to do, you can grab any EGLContext that already created by you or someone else (e.g. GLSurfaceView)and make it current then you just generate your FBO then draw with it. 
The problem is how to share the context say created by GLSurfaceView to your cross-platform c++ library. I did this by calling a static function inside the c++ to get eglcontext and surface immediately after the context been made current by Java layer. like the code below:

```
//This is a GLSurfaceView renderer method
@override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    //up to this point, we know the EGLContext 
    //has already been set current on this thread.
    //call JNI function to setup context
    graphics_library_setup_context();
}
```

the c++ counterpart

```
void setup_context() {
    context = eglGetCurrentContext();
    display = eglGetCurrentDisplay();
    surface = eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL_DRAW);
}
```